# Does the Qt Bluetooth Low Energy have the bonding procedures with encription keys?

Tags: qt, authentication, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'am playing with BLE device Xiaomi Mi Band 2 and try to make a simple Qt C++ client program on PC Linux for it.

I discovered the authentification service with characteristic and descriptor.

Now I need to run bonding procedure to save long term keys.

BLE standard describes that firstly I must connect to device, then do these three steps:

1. Switch connection to security mode with temporary keys and info exchange recuired for generation of long term keys;
2. Generate long term keys;
3. Re-istablish the connection with generated long term keys.

But I can't see all this security bonding stuff in QLowEnergy*. Encryption algorhytms?

Should I realize all of this by myself?

Comment: I don't think Qt supportes that...